# Multiple Solidity Versions in flattened file

Tags: solidity, erc-20, polygon, contract-verification, version-pragma

I have deployed a contract to Mumbai Polygon testnet. While verifying and publishing source code, the flattened file has multiple solidity versions. I got the error below.[image]

The OpenZeppelin contracts imported in the contract has version 0.8.20 and my contract has ^0.8.9. Even after changing the version to 0.8.20, I get the error while verifying my contract which has a different version.

How to solve this??